# Redirect depending on the user to different pages

Tags: php, mysql

I need a code to redirect a specific user to one page and everyone else to another. This is what I have.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if($fgmembersite->Login())
 {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
 }
}

?>
```

I need user "megan" password "megan" to go to admin.php and everyone else to login-home.php

can i do something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] === "megan") { 
        header('Location: admin.php'); 
    }else{ 
        header('Location: login-home.php');  
    }
```

Sorry Im very new to this!! I still dont understand some of this.

Oh, and if i can do the second block of code, how do i incorporate it with my first block?

Comment: where are user and password to be found? is it like $fgmembersite->user or what?

Comment: in the database, when the user trys to login i need it to check if is is the user megan. if so redirect to admin.php if not to the other page.

Comment: what is `$fgmembersite`? You need to use `header('Location: blah')` to redirect

Comment: so show us the code to get at megan etc... 'in the database' doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
if ('megan' === $_SESSION['username'] && 'megan' === $_SESSION['password']) { 
    header('Location: admin.php'); 
} else { 
    header('Location: login-home.php');  
}
```

Comment: How do I add that to my first block?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using groups for each user. For example, you can create a group field in your users table (in which you are saving the username and password) which can store a group number. Then after the user authentication has been checked (by fetching the user from the database and validating it against the entered username and password), you can just check the group field (from the fetched record) to redirect it to a particular page.

For example, after validating the username and password, you can use:

```
switch($group) {
    case '1':
        header('Location: admin.php');
        break;
    case '2':
        header('Location: login-home.php');
        break;
    default:
        // any other location you want to redirect
}
```

By using this method, you can have many users that belong to the same group and are redirected to a particular page (based on group number). This is better than checking individual username.

Just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: my users are in a msql database, how would it do this in phpMyAdmin? Im not sure I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here is what I did.

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
session_start();
$users['admin'] = array('password' => 'admin', 'redirect' => 'admin.php');
$users[$username] = array('password' => $password, 'redirect' => 'login-home.php');

if(array_key_exists($_POST['username'],$users)) {
if($_POST['password'] == $users[$_POST['username']]['password']) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('Location:'.$users[$_POST['username']]['redirect']);
    exit();
 }
else {
// invalid password
header('location: login.php');
exit;
}
}
else {
// invalid username
header('location: login.php');
exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
 if($fgmembersite->Login())
 {
      $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
 }
}


?>
```

but for some reason, some times the page wont load. Any ideas?

OK, I was working with this for about an hour, then it just stoped working...I have no ideas. Could I get some help.